# How to get the lifetime adsense earnings report using AdSense Management API?

Tags: adsense-api

I am currently trying to use the Adsense Management API to get earnings reports for today, yesterday, last 7 days, last 30 days, this month, last month and all time. I was able to get all reports but the All Time earnings report.

How should I go about extracting the total/lifetime/alltime earnings report when I do not know the starting date of the particular adsense account?

Answer (score 0):

At the time of posting there was no simple way of knowing when a users adsense account was created, so I decided to use [the date adsense was created](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=cr&ei=6ogwVaqdIcncsAW02IHAAg&fg=1#q=when%20was%20adsense%20created) which is **June 18, 2003**.

So when you want to get the All Time report using the Adsense Management API use:

```
start date: "2003-06-18"
  end date: "today"
```

Comment: I'm using Google AdSense API, can you please tell me exactly which file you have used to put this parameter? Please help

Answer (score 0):

following answer of @philip-belgrave-herbert

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "partialReportData",
        "message": "Data were not available for part of the requested date range. First date with a complete dataset: 2013-03-09"
      }
    ],
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Data were not available for part of the requested date range. First date with a complete dataset: 2013-03-09"
  }
}
```

so for the followig request string

```
startDate=2013-03-098&endDate=today
&dimension=COUNTRY_CODE
&dimension=COUNTRY_NAME
&dimension=AD_UNIT_SIZE_NAME
&metric=CLICKS
&metric=COST_PER_CLICK
&sort=COST_PER_CLICK
&useTimezoneReporting=true
&fields=rows,headers
```

> First date with a complete dataset: 2013-03-09

by use of **try / catch errors** we could adjust our date :)